# SerializeField in abstract class not appearing in inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, abstract-class

I'm running into what I think is probably a syntax issue. I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass : MonoBehavior {
    public abstract GameObject ShouldBeSerialized { get; set; }
}
```

that has a property that I want to appear in the inspector for concrete class instances:

```
public class MyConcreteClass : MyAbstractClass {
    [SerializeField] public override GameObject ShouldBeSerialized { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried adding `[SerializeField]` to both the concrate and abstract definitions. I've tried adding `[Serializable]` to the abstract class definition. I've tried making the property both virtual and non-abstract in the abstract class definition. Perhaps there's a combination of the above that I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[field: SerializeField]` instead of `[SerializeField]`

```
[field: SerializeField] public override GameObject ShouldBeSerialized { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked as well as my answer so I'll accept yours. Are you aware of what the differences are between the two approaches?

Comment: if you remove {get;set} - it's a field -> will be serialized (but depends on type)
with {get;set;} - a property -> will not

and "trick" for property
https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-7-3-field-serializefield-support.573988/

and you have warning, cause you have public field, it will be serialized without SerializeField

Comment: @WongWray depends a lot on your use case and good practices (/opinions) ;) I for instance would prefer a **field** and make it `private`. I would use this mentioned hack via property only there, where you actually want to provide it as `public` in which case it should still be `{ get; private set; }` to ensure it is only assigned via the inspector

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out via trial and error. I changed the abstract class's definition to

```
[SerializeField] public GameObject ShouldBeSerialized;
```

And then don't override or reference the field in the concrete class at all. It seems to be working but I'm getting a

> SerializeField attribute is invalid or redundant

warning.

Comment: it's redundant since a `public` **field** is already serialized by default .. see [Serialization Rules](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html#SerializationRules)